# Javascript simple Template with recursion does not append recursive child to node

Tags: javascript, html, templates, recursion

I'm currently working on a very simple Template engine in JavaScript which needs the feature of recursive Templating. The idea is to have one `<template></template>` which has a special Field that gets recursively replaced by the Template again.

```js
class Template {
  constructor(template, container) {
    this.template = template;
    this.container = container;
    this.node = [];
  }

  render_single(template, node, data) {
    // replace all occurences of {{.*?}} with template data
    node.innerHTML = template.content.children[0].innerHTML.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (match) => {
      var key = match.split(/{{|}}/).filter(Boolean)[0];
      // replace with data from data array or clear the field
      if (key in data) {
        return data[key];
      } else {
        console.log("WARNING: " + key + " not found in data array");
      }
      return "";
    });

    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/!!(.*?)!!/g, (match) => {
      var key = match.split(/!!|!!/).filter(Boolean)[0];
      switch (key.substr(0, 1)) {
        case 'R': // recursive
          var rkey = key.substr(2);
          if (rkey in data) {
            var rnode = node.querySelector('.' + rkey);
            var rtemplate = new Template(this.template, rnode);
            rtemplate.render(data[rkey]);
          }
          break;
      }
      return "";
    });
    this.container.append(node);
  }

  render(data) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.template.length; i++) {
        var node = this.template[i].content.children[0].cloneNode(true);
        this.render_single(this.template[i], node, data[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var data = [{
      name: "Test1",
      childs: [{
          name: "Test Childs 1"
        },
        {
          name: "Test Childs 2"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Test2"
    },
    {
      name: "Test3"
    },
    {
      name: "Test4"
    },
  ];
  var container = document.querySelector('#test');
  var template = container.getElementsByTagName('template');

  test = new Template(template, container);
  test.render(data);

}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <template>
    <div class="test">
      <p>Template {{name}}</p>
      <div class="childs">!!R childs!!</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sessl3r/edpL1jgy/

My problem is that only the top-level Nodes get appended. The recursive ones do not. When for testing purposes I append them to eg. `document.body` instead of `rnode` (line 28 of JS code in the example) they get appended.

Is there something needed to update the parent Node before appending it to it?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) Questions must always be self-containing without relying on external resources such as fiddles or Codepens. IF the content changes, or the link changes or is removed then your question would hold no further value to the community.

Comment: You are having 2 elements with `id="test"` which is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks. The example is only the minimal example to reproduce the problem. Changed it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you use an existing template engine, [mustache](https://mustache.github.io) or [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com), but it is ok if this is for learning purposes. I see at least one issue with your code. Your code works when you replace it with document.body since you are appending the children on a container that is not the one that you are manipulating the innerHTTML attribute for. The problem with your code lies in the following (added my comments):

```
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/!!(.*?)!!/g, (match) => {
  var key = match.split(/!!|!!/).filter(Boolean)[0];
  switch (key.substr(0, 1)) {
    case 'R': // recursive
      var rkey = key.substr(2);
      if (rkey in data) {
        var rnode = node.querySelector('.' + rkey);
        var rtemplate = new Template(this.template, rnode);
        rtemplate.render(data[rkey]); // this will append the children
      }
      break;
  }
  return ""; // this will remove the previously added children
});
```

You can clearly see the process if you move the `this.container.append(node);` line at the top of the `render_single` funciton and debug through the steps. The output will first contain the template, then replace the name, then add the children and later remove everything of the children. The same as the end result you see.

Comment: Yes it's more for fun/learning and to get into the details. And for me this problem was really interesting.

Ok I see. Yes that totally makes sense that it overwrites it again. So I think I can just replace the innerHTML.replace() with some code which just checks if there are some special elements available. That should work just fine.

Thanks for the help :)